# How to see if a user is not in a many to many relationship?

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

So I was wondering how to see if a user is not in a many to many relationship. Here is my current code:

```
seen = db.Table("seen", db.Column("user_id", db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("user.id")), db.Column("match_id", db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("user.id")))

//

seenmatch = db.relationship("User", secondary=seen, primaryjoin=(seen.c.user_id == id), secondaryjoin=(seen.c.match_id == id), backref=db.backref("seenmatches", lazy="dynamic"), lazy="dynamic")

//

users = User.query.filter_by(gender=gender).filter(or_(User.height == height, User.grade == grade)).filter(User.username != current_user.username).filter(seen.c.user_id != current_user.id).limit(10).all()
```

**.filter(seen.c.user_id != current_user.id)**

The bolded section above is what I am trying to work with. What I am trying to accomplish is to display 10 users or matches to the user. When the user refreshes the page, the same matches should not be seen again. To make sure the user doesn't see the other matches again, I have added a many to many relationship. The only problem is to get the filter to work to not show users that have already been seen. When I ran this code, it showed no users at all. If anyone can help me with this, it would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is known as an *anti join*. You can achieve it with two simple steps:

- First, perform an outer join from `User` to `seen`, with a secondary condition `seen.c.user_id == current_user.id`. This way, users that the current user has already seen will have the `seen` columns populated, while all other users will have them null.
- Then just filter to those users where the `seen` columns are null.

So, something like this:

```py
User.query \
    .outerjoin(seen, (User.id == seen.c.match_id)
                   & (seen.c.user_id == current_user.id)) \
    .filter(seen.c.user_id == None)
```